# Spring Consume Json and Return Value using Hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, api

I have a table Customers and 2 column customer_id and customer_name. I want to send id list request with json and return corresponding customer names. But I could not handle dto objects and controller-service architecture.

input dto:

```
public class CustomerSearchDto extends BaseDto {
    @ApiModelProperty(
            example = "1",
            value = "Customer Id",
            required = true,
            dataType = "Long"
    )
    private Long id;
}
```

outputdto:

```
public class CustomerDto extends BaseDto {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@ApiOperation(
            value = "Return Customer",
            response = Customer.class
    )
    @PostMapping(value = Endpoint.RRESOURCE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_BY_ID)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> getCustomersById(@RequestBody @Validated CustomerSearchDto CustomerSearchDto) {
        CustomerDto CustomerDto = new CustomerDto;
        List<CustomerDto> CustomerDtoList = CustomerService.findCustomerByIds(ids);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(CustomerDto);
    }
```

Service class method:

```
@Transactional
    public List<CustomerDto> findCustomerByIds(List<Long> customerIds) {
        List<Customer> customerList = repository.findCustomerById(CustomerIds);
        return mapper.mapAsList(CustomerList, CustomerDto.class);
    }
```

There are some mistakes in controller class. And also I am not sure about that should i define both for input and output different dto classes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it seems like you should use `CrudRepository#findAll(java.lang.Iterable<ID>)` for searching your entities by multiple ids.

Also in your specific case it's redundant to create a separate `CustomerSearchDto` as a holder for `id` - it's better to just operate with `long`s.

So just pass `List<Long> ids` as a parameter in your controller (don't forget annotate this parameter as `@RequestBody` or `@RequestParam` depending where do you want to specify these ids - in url or in body), and call `CrudRepository#findAll(ids)` from your service class.

Comment: after passing id to service, what should i return from controller class?

Comment: customerDto customerDto = new customerDto;
            List<customerDto> customerDtoList = customerService.findcustomerIds(ids);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(customerDto);

Comment: here i haven't use customerDtoList. but if i use it return then error happens.

Comment: if you find customers successfully - you should return customerDtoList, if you have nothing to return - you should either throw an exception "There are no any customers with such ids" or just return empty list, depending on your requirements

Comment: thanks @star67. can you make an example of customerdtolist class ? what methods should i put into it ?

Comment: @abidinberkay it's not necessary to create a class holder, you may return ResponseEntity.ok(customerdtolist), where customerdtolist is a List<CustomerDto>

Comment: @ApiOperation(
                  value = "Return Customer",
                  response = customer.class, responseContainer="List"
      )
      @PostMapping(value = Endpoint.RRESOURCE_customer_ID)
      public ResponseEntity<customerDto> getLocationsByLocationIds(@RequestBody @Validated @RequestParam(name = "ids", required = true) List<Long> ids) {
            List<customerDto> customerListDto = customerService.findcustomerIds(ids);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(customerListDto);
      }

Comment: Error:(51, 41) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: com.moveguides.location.common.dto.output.CustomerDto
    lower bounds: java.util.List<com.customer.common.dto.output.CustomerDto>

Comment: method's return type is ResponseEntity<customerDto>, but it should be ResponseEntity<List<customerDto >>. So change return type of controller's method

Answer (score 0):

You need not define separate input and output classes, instead, you can build and return a Map or a List as per your use-case. Also for the input you can accept List which will contain List of ids of customers you would like to retrieve.